# Scrape a website which contains img src with both jpg and webp using PHP

Tags: php, html, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I am using simplehtmldom to scrape a url. All is working fine but since that url is using images with .webp file and jpg fallback, so I cant get those images links (src). My target url is using img src like below.

```
https://static-01.daraz.pk/p/4bd8844ef66b66f4f0ba441dea6d33a6.jpg_340x340q80.jpg_.webp
```

Any idea how can i get the img src? Thanks in advance 
Below is my code

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('https://www.daraz.pk/products/opal-fire-stone-oval-shape-55-carat-i125548843-s1283634122.html?');

// Find all images 
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) 
       echo $element->src . '<br>';

// Find all links 
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

Here is the link which I am trying to scrape.

```
https://www.daraz.pk/products/opal-fire-stone-oval-shape-55-carat-i125548843-s1283634122.html?
```

Comment: What does `$html->find('img')` returns?

Comment: @CaduDeCastroAlves It just returns img src that ends with .png. Not the one that ends with .jpg_web.p

Comment: The source of that link (`echo $html;`) does not contain images with `.webp`

Comment: @Thefourthbird thanks for replying. Yes on inspect element it shows .webp image but when I view the source code it doesnt show any image. Is there a way to scrape those image src ar shown in inspect element?